# Getting a 401 status when trying to reach protected route using passport-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am using `JWT` working with `passport.js` for authentication. I have a `local strategy` that signs up and another that logs in a user. Currently, I have it return the token by doing:

```
req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    var jwtUser = {
      _id: user.id,
      email: user.email
    };
    const token = jwt.sign(jwtUser, config.passport.jwtSecret);
    return res.json({jwtUser, token});
});
```

This returns an object like:

```
{"jwtUser":
 {
    "_id":"5c55f0be9ddcf71a704d92b2",
    "email":"john.doe@example.com"
  },
 "token":"<token>" // redacted this because it contains my personal email
}
```

So I am getting a token back that is correct (I've checked using an online decoder, it gives the correct user ID and the correct email).

When I use this route to try and test whether the JWT strategy is working or not I get a 401 unauthorized access message.

**Here is my JWT strategy**

```
var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = config.passport.jwtSecret;
passport.use('jwt', new JWTstrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
  console.log('payload received: ', jwt_payload);
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
      console.log('User: ', user);
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, user);
      }
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
    });
}));
```

**My route**

```
router.get('/auth/test', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  res.send('You reached a private route.');
});
```

I have my local strategy working using the same method of calling passport.

I think I have included everything of value, if something is missing please say and I will update the OP with it.

I should note I am using postman to test this and using the authorization method of bearer token.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such error may also occur if you are using different `secretKey` for signing the token and verifying it. The same key should be used in both procedures.